# A require statement is overwriting global variables in lua

Tags: lua, include, scope, require

Consider the following two files:

### a.lua

```
function x()
    return 1
end

-- return x
```

### b.lua

```
function x()
    return 2
end

print( x() )
local y = require "a"
print( _G.x(), y )
print( x(), y() )
```

When I execute my `b.lua` I receive the following output:

```
2
1   function: 0024B710
1   1
```

which, in my opinion, is wrong. The function `x` from `a.lua` should instead be stored as `y` rather than overwriting the global variable inside `b.lua`. I know I can rectify this behaviour by using a `local` keyword inside `a.lua`.

I was just wondering whether it is undesired behaviour; and if not; what are the benefits if a `require` is also overwriting my global variables?

Comment: Isn't this question just a slight variation of "Why global by default?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be stored as `y` since you don't return it (or at least you have it commented out). If you change your `a.lua` code to `return function() return 1 end`, it should work as you expect (or add `local` as you suggested).

In general, this is why you usually see the following pattern:

```
local function a() end
local function b() end
return {a = a, b = b}
```

The you can use it as `local y = require "mymodule"; print(y.a(), y.b())` or something similar.

In terms of whether it's a desirable behavior or not, I think it's the effect of `require` being a glorified `dofile`, which executes the code in the global namespace and results in overwriting functions you may already have.

Comment: Even if I do put a `return x`, my definition inside `b.lua` gets overwritten. It might be due to, as you said; `require` being a glorified `dofile`.

Comment: Right; if you do `return x`, you still need to add "local" to the function or return it as an anonymous function.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The overwrite is because of function x() being redefined at a later point in the sequential execution of the script.  This is no different than having function x() followed by another function x() in the same file.  The most recent definition is what remains.  The use or not of 'return' has nothing to do with it.